# Passing data from one form to generate another custom form

Tags: forms

I want to create a form that our Certified Trainer has to fill out when he goes out into the field to certify a system. This form asks him to specify:

(Dropdown menus; Options seperated by commas)
1) Type of metal: Aluminum, Steel
2) Type of application: Roof, Parapet, Footpath
3) Number of users: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

When the user submits this information, another form must open up based on what information was inputed above.

For Eg. (If Aluminum was chozen, if Roof was chozen, if 2 users were chozen)
         then the form generates as follows:

1) Inspect the Aluminum system for rust, damage and deformation.
   Comments:***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**

2) Specify the Length of Roof. ***_*___** ft.
   Specify the Width of Roof. **____**_ft.

3) User 1: ***_*__*_*__*_*__**.
   User 2: **__*_*__*_*__*_***.

I hope I've explained exactly what I am trying to achieve here.

**I'm trying to pass data to another form that is generated based on the choices of the main form. I've searched everywhere for this but cannot quite get to anything specific.**

Is there a software that I use such as Infopath, Access, etc.. or can this be accomplished through php, xml, etc.. I'm quite confused.

I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction on this one. Thanks is advance for your help.

Comment: What programming language and server environment is this running in?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: Hi jpw, As of now, the form does not exist. I've just been experimenting with web forms but nothing seems to work. I can't get one form to generate another form based on the choices of the first form. I was wondering if this could be achieved in any other programming language or software or even in web forms using php, jquery, etc..

Comment: I'm trying to achieve something similar to an Advanced Search, where the user selects a few choices to narrow down on the search. Similar concept but its not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There's literally tons of different ways to accomplish this obviously, but with limited knowledge of programming this might be rather difficult - I don't know of any out-of-the-box solution that could help you - but a google search might find something.

Probably the easiest way would be to use PHP, and submit the first form to a specific php page that will read the post data and then redirect to the 2nd form based on that data.  Here's some sample (code may not be 100% correct)

```
if( $_POST['metal_type'] == 'Aluminum' ){
    redirect to the aluminum form page
}else{
    redirect somewhere else
}
```

That should get you started - the specifics will depend upon your form and exactly what you need to do.